# Nested If statement Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm new to PS and I'm trying to find a user or group (Azure) based on user input `$guid`. If a user is found, I would like for the script to not look for groups. My script is not working, and I'm unsure what mistake I am doing. I would gladly appreciate it if someone could point out what's wrong here and how to correct it. Thank you!

```
#Find user/group
$user = Get-AzADUser -ObjectId $guid
$group = $false

if ($user)
{
    $user | FL Mail, MailNickName; break
}

else
{
    Get-AzADGroup -ObjectId $guid | FL DisplayName, MailNickName
    $group = $true

    if ($group -eq $false)
    {
        Write-Warning "No matches found."
    }
}
```

Comment: You're setting `$group = $true` before `if ($group -eq $false)`, so your `if` block is by definition never entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few recommendations:

- Remove `$group = $true` as recommended by `mklement0`
- Also Change this line from `Get-AzADGroup -ObjectId $guid | FL DisplayName, MailNickName` to `$group = Get-AzADGroup -ObjectId $guid`
- Remove break from the following line, it's only required in loops `$user | FL Mail, MailNickName; break`
- Use $null to initialize variables instead of $false

This is how your script should look like:

```
#Find user/group
$user = Get-AzADUser -ObjectId $guid

# it is better to initialize a variable with $null instead of $false
$group = $null

if ($user)
{
    # also no need to "break" use if you are not using loop so I removed "break"
    $user | FL Mail, MailNickName
}

else
{
    $group = Get-AzADGroup -ObjectId $guid
    
    if ($group -eq $false)
    {
        Write-Warning "No matches found."
    }
    else {
        $group | FL DisplayName, MailNickName
    }

}
```

Just to make your script smaller:

```
#Find user/group
$user = $null
$group = $null

$user = Get-AzADUser -ObjectId $guid
$group = Get-AzADGroup -ObjectId $guid

if ($user)
{
    $user | FL Mail, MailNickName
}
if ($group) 
{
    $group | FL DisplayName, MailNickName
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The first one is a lot easier for me to understand :) However, I wasn't getting the warning message. Changing '($group -eq $false)' to ($group -eq $null) worked though. Thank you, again!

Answer (score 0):

Why not simplify to something like this:

```
#Find user or group
$object = Get-AzADUser -ObjectId $guid
if (!$object) { $object = Get-AzADGroup -ObjectId $guid } # not a user; try group
if ($object) { $object | Select-Object DisplayName, MailNickName }
else { Write-Warning "No matches found." }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you explain why the name of the variable didn't have to change when using the Get-AzADGroup command?

Comment: @PotWang That is because I'm only trying to get an object, whether it's a user or a group. By using the same variable, all you need to check afterwards if you have an object or not.